# How can you detect a XAML designer window in a VSPackage

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, envdte, vspackage

In my VSPackage I have an event handler for the WindowActivated event on the [EnvDTE.WindowEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.windowevents?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) interface.

In my code I check whether the activated window is WinForms designer with (in VB.NET)

```
If TypeOf GotFocus.Object Is IDesignerHost Then
  ...
End if
```

or an ASP designer window with

```
If TypeOf GotFocus.Object Is EnvDTE.HTMLWindow Then
  ...
End if
```

What is the best way to detect when a XAML designer window is activated?

Of course, I can check the file extension in the caption (GotFocus.Caption), but I wondered if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

File extension probably isn't a good idea because you can open a .XAML file with the stock code editor as well :-)

Easiest way I can think of, would be to leverage the [IVsMonitorSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsmonitorselection) service.

Call [GetCmdUIContextCookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsmonitorselection.getcmduicontextcookie) with the the XAML Designer context guid {e9b8485c-1217-4277-b6d6-c825a5ac1968} (found with the [Component Diagnostics extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.ComponentDiagnostics) ), and then call [IsCmdUIContextActive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsmonitorselection.iscmduicontextactive) to determine if the designer is activated.